# Low RAM Usage & high GPU usage, HF Datasets not helping in fine-tuning LM

Tags: ram, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I've been trying to finetune "roBERTa base" model using the MLM task. (https://huggingface.co/course/en/chapter7/3) with the sample training dataset of 20_000 points, preprocessed according to the need.

I've used HuggingFace datasets (https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.6.1/en/package_reference/loading_methods#datasets.load_dataset) to read the data points & I am also using the data collate function to achieve dynamic masking for every batch.

I am using g4dn.2xlarge (https://instances.vantage.sh/aws/ec2/g4dn.2xlarge - 32GB RAM, 16GB GPU, 8 vCPUs) instance for fine-tuning `Roberta-base` MLM task with a brach size of 8 & each datapoint is of 512 sequence length. And I am using HuggingFace Trainer API

With the above config, **I observed GPU memory was very high, 95%+ and system RAM utilization was around 13-15%!**

I did set follow the https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v1.12.0/cache.html & set `IN_MEMORY_MAX_SIZE` to ~25GB, but no luck

```
import datasets
datasets.config.IN_MEMORY_MAX_SIZE = 24_696_061_952
train_dataset = load_dataset('pandas',
                             data_files={'train': 'path to pickle file'}, 
                             keep_in_memory=True)
```

But RAM usage remained as it is. **How can I make full utilization of RAM & GPU memory?**

I've to take 20_000 as the sample for this experiment but I've ~1 Million data points, which I will be using in the future for full-fledged training, post-resolution to this problem

Any suggestions?

Huggingface discussion: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/low-ram-usage-high-gpu-usage-datasets-not-helping/29269/1

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to fill your RAM to make your training go faster. On the other hand filling your GPU memory (by increasing the batch size) is often a good way indeed.

HF Datasets uses memory mapping to load the data from your disk. This way only  one batch of data is loaded in memory at a time, leaving lots of memory for any data processing or augmentation you may do during training.